# Borderlands 2 - nobody dies!

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm a newbie gamer with beginner questions.   I have Borderlands 2 on an Xbox One and I can't get past the first level. I can't even get past a single enemy. I keep emptying bullets into them from close range and they just won't die. Skeletons,pirates and the Alien dog things, doesn't matter.  Nothing dies, they're all indestructible. What am I doing wrong?  Is there somewhere in Settings that's turned to the wrong level?  Any advice welcome.

Comment: When you look at the enemies, the health bar should display the level. Is it a lot higher than yours? Also, do you actually mean enemies aren't taking damage and are unkillable, or just that they're hard to kill? That would change how we'd handle answering the question.

Comment: I'll take a look at health next time I play.  But given, so far, there's always about 5 of them to one of me,  I don't know how easy it is to do. 'Unkillable' means 20-30 machine gun bullets into the body from almost no distance, before they invariably kill me.

Comment: It would help to have a screenshot of the area then we might be able to help more

Comment: you entered a dlc area which is way to high level, just play the main story line before trying that again ... -.-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no Skeletons in the very start of the game. I suspect that you jumped into Scarlett's DLC (this one has pirates) or Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep (This one starts with skeletons) where it is meant to be played after you have completed the base story first.

The enemy levels for Scarlett is 15-30 and for Tiny Tina is 30-35 on Normal. Which if you just started and are level 1, are way too hard (if not impossible) for you to kill them.

Comment: Maybe they're on Pre-sequel.  Both games are on the same disk. It's one of the first locations,  a bay where skeletons shoot arrows at you and are unkillable (by me)

Comment: You tagged the game Borderlands 2, and the answer was provided given based on that. This is what the start of the base Borderlands 2 game looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKtho5ABUnk No Skeletons or pirates.

Comment: @KevinRyan Based on your description, it's almost definitely Tiny Tina's Assault.  You may have ended up there by using a Fast Travel machine to initiate the DLC.